# How to use expand.grid() in R language using a dynamic string expression to define the grid

Tags: r

Suppose these lines have already executed:

```
allitems = c('B','N','D','C','E','M')
b = c(0,1)
```

Now, how can we cause expand.grid() to use those 2 variables to generate data.frame p, which is the equivalent grid of the following line of (working) code?

```
p = expand.grid(B=b, N=b, D=b, C=b, E=b, M=b)
```

Thanks.

The functions expression() and eval() did not seem to help. Passing the string "B=b, N=b, D=b, C=b, E=b, M=b" to expand.grid() did not work either, although that solution would be perfectly acceptable too.  I would prefer to use expand.grid() rather write something from scratch. But I would write something from scratch if I have to. It just seems like it would be a waste to completely discard the nice function expand.grid().

Comment: not using your requested function, but there is also `permutations(2, 6, b, repeats.allowed=TRUE)`

Comment: @J.Won: What package is that in?

Comment: That function is in `gtools`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `do.call`:

```
do.call(expand.grid, 
        setNames(rep(list(b), length(allitems)), 
                 allitems))
```